# How to add filters(picklist) headers on vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have developed a VF page with 5 columns. My requirement is that, I need to add filters on the header and the results should show based on the Filter header. The filters are picklist values. So, if the user selects any value on that picklist field, the result should show based on that value only.

I am not able to paste the code, as it is big. Sorry.
Kindly help me, so that I can learn

Comment: you could paste the parts that are relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like when user select anything in picklist pass the value in controller and add this in query.

```
Example: if user select Name  = 'Test' then in query add Where Name= 'Test' and display the result in your query.
```

for pass the value in controller you can use **apex:param** tag to pass the value and bind this with your controller variable.